# Get previous and next monday date by given date

Tags: php

How we can get previous week monday date and next week monday date by provided date.Eample: if $date = '2015-04-08' (y-m-d format).
then function returns, previous monday date = 2015-03-30
and next monday date = 2015-04-13

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
echo "Next Monday:". date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday', strtotime($givenDate)));
echo "Previous Monday:". date('Y-m-d', strtotime('previous monday', strtotime($givenDate)));
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last week Monday'));
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next week Monday'));
```

or whatever you want http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: This is only compare by today date, i want as mention whatever date is provided in function then it works by that date and gives monday dates.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
$nextMonday = new \DateTime('2015-04-08 next Monday');
$previousMonday = new \DateTime('2015-04-08 Monday ago');
```