# php - using strtotime date goes to 1970s

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to get next `monday` for a given date using `strttotime` but I am getting dates from `Jan 1970` as ouput. Below is my code line which is written for the getting date of next monday, I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29515147/3584032). Can anyone please help me understanding why this is happening. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
$date_init = date('Y m d', strtotime('next monday', strtotime('2016 06 22')));
```

Expected Output:

```
2016 06 27
```

Actual Output:

```
1970 01 05
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string `2016 06 22` is not a valid date format according to the manual. Try to add hyphens:

```
$date_init = date('Y m d', strtotime('next monday', strtotime('2016-06-22')));
```

You can find all valid date formats here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$date_init = date('Y m d', strtotime('next monday', strtotime('22-06-2016')));
```

'2016 06 22' needs to be formated to one of the formats mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

`2016 06 02` is **not one of the accepted date formats** [as described in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). For this reason, the inner call to `strtotime` returns `FALSE` [as defined in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) in case the given time string cannot be parsed.

Since this is not a valid input for the outer `strtotime` for the `$now` parameter, **it takes the epoch, or January 1, 1970, as basis for it's calculations**.

As a result, you end up with the next monday after January 1, 1970.

**Removing the spaces from the initial date** string will solve this:

```
$date_init = date('Y m d', strtotime('next monday', strtotime('20160622')));
```